# how can i select and upload multiple images from CAMERA

Tags: react-native

```
select multiple images from camera not working 

****  working for single image capture and selection  *****



imageCamera(){
      this.setState({imageSourceText:'Camera'})
      let imagearray ={}
      ImagePicker.openCamera({compressImageMaxWidth:400,
        compressImageMaxHeight:400,multiple: true
        }).then(image => { .
```

here i get only single image in response

```
      this.setState({ImageSource:image})
      console.log("cameraimagearray======="+this.state.ImageSource)

        imagearray = {uri:image.path}
        let tempArray = []
        tempArray.push(imagearray)

        console.log("tempArray from Camera ============="+tempArray);
        this.setState({ImageSourceviewarray:tempArray})

        console.log("image from Camera ============="+image.path);
        }

      );
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation of this other component, it's suppose that does what you want and is similar to what you are using!

> https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use `openCamera` and capture multiple photos. It works for a single photo only. One solution is to manually open camera, take as many photos as you need, and when you close it use `openPicker` and select multiple photos from there:

```
ImagePicker.openPicker({
  multiple: true
}).then(images => {
  console.log(images);
});
```

Comment: How can I ask the user to choose one of the "Camera Or Gallery"?

Comment: @OliverD You can display a custom dialog with two options, "Camera Or Gallery".